# Sequence of OnItemCommand and OnItemDataBound

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on a `<asp:Repeater>` with the code like this

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptMyList" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptMyList_OnItemDataBound"  OnItemCommand="rptMyList_OnItemCommand" >
```

There's also a `<asp:LinkButton>` within the `<asp:Repeater>`.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbClick" runat="server" Text="CLICK" CommandName="click"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("VAL") %>' CausesValidation="false" ></asp:LinkButton>
```

When I click the `LinkButton` I expect the `rptMyList_OnItemCommand` would run, setting the view variable at the backend, and have the updated variable being processed with `OnItemDataBound`.

However, I found it's actually `rptMyList_OnItemDataBound` being executed before `rptMyList_OnItemCommand` in debug mode.

Is it correct sequence and any way I could enforce `rptMyList_OnItemCommand` executing before `rptMyList_OnItemDataBound`?

Answer (score 1):

The [OnItemDataBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx) event occurs after an item in the Repeater control is data-bound but before it is rendered on the page.

The [OnItemCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) occurs when a button is clicked in the Repeater control.

So the answer is no. You can not click a button before the item is rendered.

If it is an already rendered page use the [Page.IsPostBack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx) property to handle that situation.

Comment: While your answer can't really resolve my situation, the hint on `IsPostBack` reminded me to set a condition check when the page is rendered. And I further added a explicit manual refresh on variable / view status in `OnItemCommand` so the content could probably show now. Cheers man.